# How to check if the element selected/clicked is multiple of "n" using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have 'n' `li` elements inside a `ul`. I want to alert a message only if the `li` `selected/clicked` is a multiple of "n"(let it be 3).

In the below example, alert must be shown only if I click the 3rd, 6th and 9th `li` element:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your question says the: “*alert must be shown only if I click the 3rd, 6th and 9th li,*” did you mean “**and**” or did you mean “**or**”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, we can use `nth-child` as well.

```js
$('ul').find('li:nth-child(3n)').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the modulo `%` for this with the help of `index()` to get the index of the clickd `li`.

We should add `1` since the index is zero based :

```
if (($(this).index() + 1) % n == 0) {
    //Your logique here
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var n = $('ul>li').length;

$('li').click(function() {
  var currentIndex = $(this).index();

  if ( (currentIndex + 1) % n == 0) 
  {
    console.log('Alert here')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the use for the count variable?

Comment: It can be achieved by simple `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` selector

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector

```js
$('li:nth-of-type(3n)').click(function() {
  console.log('Alert here')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this:

```
var number = 3;
$("ul li").click(function(){
  var i = $(this).index() + 1
  if(i % number == 0) {
    console.log("You clicked on either element 3,6 or 9")
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var number = 3;
$("ul li").click(function(){
  var i = $(this).index() + 1
  if(i % number == 0) {
    console.log("You clicked on either element 3,6 or 9")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
    <li>list item 6</li>
    <li>list item 7</li>
    <li>list item 8</li>
    <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can use `$(ul li:nth-child(3n)).click()` it will take each third element.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `index()`

UPDATE : Directly running this code should satisfy your requirement. N=3 in this example.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hgoadjv/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var N = 3;
  $("ul li").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    if(index%N == 0) {
      alert("Is a multiple of "+N);
    } else {
      alert("Is not a multiple of "+N);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```